# I am trying to understand what this particular inequality means

Tags: functions, inequality

It is part of a paper that I am reading and they mention a variable x which denotes preference. Apart from that, the distribution function and derivative function
are F(x) and f(x) respectively, where F(x) and f(x) satisfy

d ((F(x)/f(x)))/ dx < 0

It would be really helpful if someone could explain me this inequality. I really don't think there is any information that's relevant here in the paper. But please let me know if you need more information. Thanks!

Here is a [link](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/330248560_Optimal_Subsidies_for_Green_Products_A_Maximal_Policy_Benefit_Perspective) to the paper. I am talking about assumption 1 at the bottom of page 5.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Showing the reference you are reading will help others answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

let $f(x)$ be a continuous function, and let $F(x)=\int{f(x)}dx$

Now that we have $f(x)$ and $F(x)$, we crate a new function
$$G(x)=\frac{F(x)}{f(x)}$$
You inequality basically means
$$G’(x)<0$$
that is, $G(x)$ is a strictly decreasing function.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! I understand this part but I wanted to know if there is a reason that they divided the function with it's derivative and then checked if it's increasing. Particularly, what is significance of this division.

Comment: It all depends on the context. If you give us more information in the paper ( or link it). But, usually, since $F(x)$ is related to the average height of the area and $f(x)$ is the height of the area. They may be checking the rate of change of the relative height to the average.

Comment: Thanks, I have added the link. Please let me know if it helps you in interpreting the inequality